# How to call the MainActivity from another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have my MainActivity, and I create an Intent to a SecondActivity, when a button is pressed,
I want to return to activity. But when I create the intent and pass (this, MainActivity.class) through the constructor, I get an error: The intent constructor is undefined. Can someone help me?

public void goBackToMainActivity(View view) {

```
    //Button for retrieving the user's current location:
    final Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);

    //Listens for button presses and releases:
    backButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //When the button is pressed:
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //Change image for touch indication:
                backButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);                           
            //When the button is released:
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //Change image back to default:
                backButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button_selected);  
                goBackToMainActivity();
            } 
                return false;
            }

        });
}

public void goBackToMainActivity() {
    finish();
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);      
    startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the source code to look into?

Comment: paste your logcat whatever error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are creating the intent inside an `OnClickListener`, thus you need to use the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
```

The reason is that if you do not specify `SecondActivity.this`, you are actually passing the `OnClickListener` into the intent constructor.

Comment: Also, since OP wants to return to the first activity and not create a new instance of it, I would add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

Comment: Thank you all. Ive been doing Java for about 2 years in HighSchool and Im dripping into Android and Im just learning to tie my shoes again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your goback method:

```
public void goBackToMainActivity() {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);      
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First clear all the existing activities by writing code: 
`startActivity(intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));`

Then call the intent to the MainActivity

```
Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling finish() on button click in second activity to return to the main activity.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 finish();
}
```

Comment: not a good answer, the system could have destroyed the first activity.

Comment: this not proper way to do so

Comment: Thank you! I dont know if the finish() is what fixed it, but I didnt have an onClick listener, I had an OnTouch listener because I wanted to change button images based if if the button was pressed or release. Once I took the code out of the if/else statement of the onTouch listener and separated it into a called method, it worked. Does anyone know if its normal, that I have to press the button twice before it works? The first button press simply makes a click noise but does no action? On the second click, it will preform the action.

Comment: @DarrenKing: It is better if you post the source code for a good understanding.
As @Lawrence mentioned in his reply, whatever listener you are implementing, if it being implemented in an inner class, the first parameter `this` in intent constructor will not refer to your activity but for the inner class. and there is no intent constructors defined for listener classes.